# ¿Como cierro un documento XML que se abre con XDocument en c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xdocument

Quiero guardar varias veces un documento XML en una cierta dirección, La primera vez que guardo mi documento no hay problema, la situación viene después de que quiero sobre escribirlo con nueva información. Intente hacerlo con las siguientes lineas de codigo:

```
  XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Comentarios", new XElement(usuario,comentario.ComentarioU)));

 doc.Save(directorio + "\\XML\\comentarios.xml");    

                if (File.Exists(directorio + "\\XML\\comentarios.xml"))
                {

    doc=null;
    doc=new XDocument();
                    retornoLista = abrirxml(comentario,usuario);

                }
```

Después de la primera vez me sale un error que dice que mi archivo esta siendo utilizado, entonces quisiera ver la forma de cerrar mi archivo cada vez que lo abra.

Codigo de abrirXml()

```
public List<string> abrirxml(comentario comentario,string usuario)
       {
            var directorio = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            XmlNodeList xmlnode;
            XmlNodeList xmlnodeSub;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(directorio + "XML\\comentarios.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            xmldoc.Load(fs);
            xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Comentarios").Item(0).ChildNodes;

           foreach (XmlNode node in xmlnode)
           {
               listadoComments.Add(node.Name.ToString()+"|"+node.InnerText);
           }

           return listadoComments;
       }
```

Comment: Hola, cual es el código de `abrirxml(comentario,usuario)` ?

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra ya añadi el codigo de ese metodo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deberías emplear un bloque `using` para que se realice un `Close` y un `Dispose`del `stream` al archivo `xml`.

```
public List<string> abrirxml(comentario comentario,string usuario)
{
    var directorio = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    XmlNodeList xmlnode;
    XmlNodeList xmlnodeSub;
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(directorio + "XML\\comentarios.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        xmldoc.Load(fs);
    }

    xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Comentarios").Item(0).ChildNodes;

   foreach (XmlNode node in xmlnode)
   {
       listadoComments.Add(node.Name.ToString()+"|"+node.InnerText);
   }

   return listadoComments;
}
```